# How can I improve cyphering speed of the Bouncy Castle API?

Tags: c#, performance, encryption, aes, bouncycastle

I'm developing a software in C#, until now I was using the cryptographic library included in .NET (especially `AesCryptoServiceProvider`), but now I've special needs and I need to move to the Bouncy Castle API's. I've done some tests and I found out that these API are slower in comparison of what it's included in the .NET framework. Any idea on how to improve their performance?
This is the cipher that I'm using:
`IBufferedCipher cipher = new CtsBlockCipher(new CbcBlockCipher(new AesFastEngine()));`

To be more specific, I need to move to the Bouncy Castle API's because I need both input and output file with the same length and the .NET `RijndaelManaged` (the only class that can assure that kind of behavior) is way slower than `AesCryptoServiceProvider`.

To encrypt a file of 1.7MB with `AesCryptoServiceProvider` it takes about 40ms in my machine and about 170ms with Bouncy Castle. It doesn't look like much, but I need to use this software in a server with hundreds of requests per minutes...

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it sounds like you need a stream cipher, maybe look into [Salsa20](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salsa20). It's supposed to be fast in general. And Bouncy Castle has an implementation ([Salsa20Engine](http://www.bouncycastle.org/viewcvs/viewcvs.cgi/csharp/crypto/src/crypto/engines/Salsa20Engine.cs?revision=1.8&view=markup)).

Comment: I don't know why, but speed wise the `AesCryptoServiceProvider` class is much faster of the `Salsa20Engine` in Bouncy Castle.

Comment: Maybe, it's a native code issue. There are a lot of processor optimizations that can be done for encryption, it's probably why the built-in managed api is so much slower too for Rijndael. If you are really serious about speed you could looke at the public domain  assembly optimized versions:http://cr.yp.to/snuffle.html#speed

Comment: Hi @jbtule. Just to be sure I got you, with the Salsa20Engine, I can perform streamed PGP encryption? If so at what point in the encryption process do I add the Salsa20 engine? I am trying to optimize an existing large file process encryption, using a buffered stream with byte-by-byte on the fly encryption. I do not see where to fit in the Salsa20 and still use the parameters(filename,moddate and key)